# Cassandra - using "date" vs "text" types for a partition date key

Tags: cassandra

We have a schema where the partition key will be a date (yyyy-MM-dd) and we are thinking about choosing the data type between **text** and **date** for this partition key.

Does one data type provide benefits over the other and how would they differ in querying/storage?

Here is an example schema.

```
CREATE TABLE test.user_sessions (
    sess_date date (or text),
    sess_starttime timestamp,
    event_type text,
    total_req int,
    ended_at timestamp
    PRIMARY KEY (sess_date, sess_starttime)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra Date Type :

> Value is a date with no corresponding time value; Cassandra encodes date as a 32-bit integer representing days since epoch (January 1, 1970)

Cassandra Text Type :

> UTF-8 encoded string; 16 bit for each character

**If you store  date (yyyy-MM-dd) as date data type each entry will only take 32-bit. On the other hand if you store the date as text it will take 10*16 = 160 bit storage.**

Comment: This is a good point. Thanks. After thinking more on this, I see a problem in using "date" type on the client side (am using c#). I need to map it to a custom LocalDate type (defined in Cassandra driver lib). This means that any other project dependent on this class also needs to import Cassandra lib. Ofcourse there is a way to map into a neutral class to not have a dependency on Cassandra. It's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 3):

As per your comments, if you need maximum portability simply store the information as a timestamp (that is a 64-bit number) corresponding to the something like yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 (a truncated time stamp). You can't go wrong with an "universal" number...